# Store and retrieve VSD file into SQL FILETABLE

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

How to save a `.VSD` file into a FileTable in SQL Server 2012? And also need to retrieve and display the `.VSD` file on a web page?

Filetable column : `file_stream varbinary(max)`

Any help? Thank you.

Code used:

```
sfileName = "sample.vsd"
Dim fs As New FileStream(sfileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(fs.Length))
```

Answer (score 0):

VARBINARY(MAX) would be the correct data type to store binary data and you will want to use the FILESTREAM attribute. If you assume that this is the only type of file you will be storing in your table, then you are good. If you need to store multiple types of files you will want to add another column to capture the file type and then have your application display it correctly.

Check out the following post that should give you a better understanding. Article mentions SQL 2008 but it is applicable to 2012 and 2014:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2008/04/14/sql-server-2008-makes-it-easy-to-manage-blobs-and-files.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link. The file table does store multiple types of files. I'm having issue only with VSD file. I'm able to store and retrieve files with types xml, pdf.

Comment: If you are storing the Raw bytes of the file you should have no problem retrieving those bytes. So your problem would not be on the DB side. Your issue is more than likely on the application side and how you render or transmit the file to the client.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the way I'm saving the file to DB. Because when I try to open the VSD file from the physical path of the FILE TABLE, it is giving me error - Microsoft office Visio Viewer cannot load the specified URL or file.

Comment: Dim fs As New FileStream(sfileNam, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(fs.Length))

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to save and retrieve the Visio (.vsd) file from the FILETABLE in SQL server 2012. 
I tried to save the Visio file to the latest version of Visio (.vsdx) but it didn't work.

The work around for it is save the .vsd file to PDF or Image file. Then save the file to SQL Server FILETABLE using the code mentioned in my question.